# CSS autocomplete in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

I have already gone through several similar questions on SO and elsewhere; none of them provides an answer, not a working one anyway.

When I type `<div class="...`, why doesn't Eclipse provide me the autocomplete list of available CSS classes in the project? AutoComplete works in PHP code without a problem.

Solutions I have tried:

0. Trying CTRL + SPACE shortcut.
1. Checking Code Assist options in Preferences.
2. Installing Aptana plug-in.

I'm using Eclipse Luna (PDT).

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that what you are looking for, is supported. I see where you are coming from, however the official documentation does not seem to offer what you want to achieve.

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/code_assist_concept.htm

Comment: I guess the link you have provided is only about PHP auto-completion. Otherwise Eclipse DOES support HTML tags auto-completion, which are not listed on the page, so  I'm hoping the same to be the case with CSS classes.